# RealVnc android viewer sample app unkown error

Tags: java, android, vnc

I've ran into some error when trying to connect to my RaspberryPi( VNC server)
, I did not make any edits to the code so I don't know why its not working
Im sending run log so maybe someone will push me into right direction

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.realvnc.vncsdk.sample.basicViewerAndroid, PID: 6200
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.realvnc.vncsdk.sample.basicViewerAndroid-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.realvnc.vncsdk.sample.basicViewerAndroid-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libvncsdk.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1567)
        at com.realvnc.vncsdk.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:97)
        at com.realvnc.vncsdk.Library.ensureLoaded(Library.java:94)
        at com.realvnc.vncsdk.Logger.<clinit>(Logger.java:102)
        at com.realvnc.vncsdk.Logger.createAndroidLogger(Logger.java:50)
        at com.realvnc.vncsdk.sample.basicViewerAndroid.SdkThread.initSdk(SdkThread.java:95)
        at com.realvnc.vncsdk.sample.basicViewerAndroid.SdkThread.access$000(SdkThread.java:44)
        at com.realvnc.vncsdk.sample.basicViewerAndroid.SdkThread$1.run(SdkThread.java:70)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```